# LAMMPS input card in an NVIDIA GPU

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, graphical-processing-unit

I want to simulate the attached model for a Cu NP in Ar using my GPU, but I got erratic results. All looks well when I simulate it in my CPU with the command:

```
mpirun --use-hwthread-cpus lmp -in in
```

and, in my understanding, it should be the same input card for a GPU but executed with the command

```
lmp -sf gpu -pk gpu 1 -in in
```

However, the results look very different between both. What do you think about this?

Thanks a lot!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ozgBJKeGdV7sORw_MYhkGrGVl9C0B534/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: It looks like this issue may have been resolved: https://matsci.org/t/lammps-input-card-in-a-nvidia-gpu/37400/6. If you could summarize what fixed the problem, it would make a good answer here as well. Also, in general, if you post a question to multiple forums, its best to include links to the other versions in the question. This avoids users putting effort into a problem that may already have been solved elsewhere and allows future users to find the answer more easily wherever it is posted.

Comment: Hi Tyberius, thanks for your message. Yes, it is the same question! sorry for not put the link immediately, I was a very busy week.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to make sure other users were aware the question was resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered on the [matsci LAMMPS forum](https://matsci.org/t/lammps-input-card-in-a-nvidia-gpu/37400/5) by Axel Kohlmeyer.

To summarize, there is a [known bug](https://github.com/lammps/lammps/issues/2621) (still unresolved as of 7/28/2021) that leads to a corrupted neighbor list when using GPUs in combination with a hybrid pair style. Axel suggests using the command `lmp -sf gpu -pk gpu 1 neigh no -in in` as a workaround.